# Struggling to plot CSV data sets of different lengths

Tags: python, data-analysis

I have imported data from 2 data sets (in CSV format) they both plot fine separately. however, when I combine them to be plotted on the same chart I get the below error. If I remove plt.plot(cell_11_cycle1.QQo_mAh / 0.020639, cycle1.Ecell_V) line they plot fine again. I think it is to do with the length of the data sets s there any way to fix this without manipulating the raw data? this is my first time doing data analysis using python.

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

cell_10_cycle0 = Cell_10[Cell_10.cycle_number == 0]
cell_10_cycle1 = Cell_10[Cell_10.cycle_number == 1]
cell_11_cycle0 = Cell_11[Cell_11.cycle_number == 0]
cell_11_cycle1 = Cell_11[Cell_11.cycle_number == 1]

plt.plot(cell_10_cycle0.QQo_mAh / 0.021638, cycle0.Ecell_V)
plt.plot(cell_10_cycle1.QQo_mAh / 0.021638, cycle1.Ecell_V)
plt.plot(cell_11_cycle0.QQo_mAh / 0.020639, cycle0.Ecell_V)
plt.plot(cell_11_cycle1.QQo_mAh / 0.020639, cycle1.Ecell_V)
plt.legend(['Cell 10 Cycle 0', 'Cell 10 Cycle 1', 'Cell 11 Cycle 0', 'Cell 1 Cycle 1'])
plt.xlabel('capacity /mAh/g')
plt.ylabel('Ecell /V')
plt.title('600C Heat Treated Material')

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (808,) and (896,)
```

Comment: the data is coming from two different csv files

Comment: the error you are getting is because your x and y arrays are different length.  You can confirm with a couple of print statements before you try to plot to QA what is going on.  Given that they are different length, I'm not sure a plot makes sense... ??

Answer (score 0):

Column cell_11_cycle1.QQo_mAh contains 808 elements, column cycle1.Ecell_V contains 896 elements. Both columns must have the same length for matplotlib to be able to properly plot your data. You could change:

```
plt.plot(cell_11_cycle1.QQo_mAh / 0.020639, cycle1.Ecell_V)
```

to:

```
plt.plot(cell_11_cycle1.QQo_mAh / 0.020639, cycle1.Ecell_V.iloc[:808])
```

This takes only the first 808 elements of your y-data. So you will lose a part of the data.

The better option seems to check your data source, there might be a part of the x-values missing or maybe you are plotting two values that are not related to each other.